# C++ Template Branching

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have an interesting case of trying to have branch within a template function where the path is dependent on the interface implemented by the template type. This branch then determines the constructor of the return value. I am unsure if this type of branching is possible. The alternative it to split the function into two different function and have the user call the one that corresponds to the desired branch.

My question is twofold:

**How can I perform the if statement based on the interface implementation?**

**How can I get the function to compile when the interface is not implemented?** For example `int` does not have a constructor with two parameters.

```
template<typename T>
T GetObject()
{
    // If T implements interface, call interface constructor
    if(typeid(T) implements inteface IInterface) // How can this be done?
        return T(1, 2);

    // If T does not implement the interface, call parameterless constructor
    else
        return T();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your templating example is impossible, but there may be an easy way to accomplish your actual goal.

Comment: This is part of a framework within my software for serialzation. This is the point where either the return object is assigned based on some stored bytes or the returned object has child objects which need to be fetched. The interface in my question is the ISerializable interface I have created. Barry got me the exact thing I needed. I asked this question to try to combine my `T GetObject()` and `ISerializable GetSerializedObject()` functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can easily deduce, your code as is has no way of working (even though I wish it did) because regardless of what you put in your if statements, every line has to be compiled - even if some will later be removed during optimization. Even if you had the correct line for:

```
if(typeid(T) implements inteface IInterface)
    return T(1,2); // <---
```

The second line would still be compiled for `int`, which is no good.

What you want is SFINAE: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error. Basically, you intentionally write a *declaration* that cannot compile but as long as there's an available overload that will compile, that's good enough! So to that end, we just take advantage of some type traits and the magic, yet incredibly simple, [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
// this overload will only exist if T is-a IInterface
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<IInterface, T>::value,
    T
>::type
GetObject() {
    return T(1,2);
}

// this overload will only exist if T is NOT an IInterface
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<IInterface, T>::value,
    T
>::type
GetObject() {
    return -1;
}

// explicit for int - put this *last*
// due to complications with specialization
template <>
int GetObject() {
    return 0;
}
```

Although given Herb Sutter's [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) on function specialization, probably better to use overloading:

```
template <typename T> struct empty_ { };

template <typename T>
T GetObject() { return GetObjectImpl(empty_<T>{} ); }

// the int version: overload, not specialization
int GetObjectImpl( empty_<int> ) { 
    return 0;
}

// the other two versions are the same as before
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<... same as before ...>::type
GetObjectImpl(empty_<T> ) {
    return T(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. A minute of massaging into my project and your answer worked perfectly. Thanks for answering both questions and quickly.