# strange g++ compiler behavior to typeid inside template function

Tags: c++, templates

I try to create some polymorphic class member template function to handle multiple types:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void AddType(T value);
private:
    bool b_val;
    int i_val;
    std::string str_val;
}

template<typename T>
void MyClass::AddType(T value)
{    
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(bool))
    {        
        b_val = value;
    }
    else if(typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {        
        i_val = value;
    }
    else if(typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
    {
         str_val = val
    }
}
```

usage:

```
MyClass message;
std::string s = "string";
int i = 123;
message.AddType(s);
message.AddType(i);
```

for some reason I get compiler error:

```
error: assigning to 'bool' from incompatible type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'
        b_val = value;
                ^~~~~

note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'MyClass::AddType<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' requested here
    message.AddType(s);
```

why the compiler guesses the T is std::string?

Update: [reproducable error](https://godbolt.org/z/v5OIKu)

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/7lfQCB)

Comment: Your error mentions `std::string`, but that type is nowhere in sight in the actual code. Post a [mcve].

Comment: I fixed your question to actually trigger the error (`int` and `char` are implicitly convertible ot one another, so that ended up "working"). But the answer is just that `if` and `typeid` are runtime constructs and *must* be valid at compile time. Try with `if constexpr` and `std::is_same`, or simply two function overloads.

Comment: As for your goal, as evident from the code you *do* show, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005199/c-template-branching for the problem description

Comment: that's the strangeness of the error - I never used it with strings.

Comment: What compiler are you using? In addition maybe you could rethink your design. If you are using templates anyway it could make sense to use a template member variale, too. I.e. `T val;` and get rid of the type check completely.

Comment: @Quentin, I've never used std::string in this context, your fix just confuses

Comment: @folibis Feel free to revert my edit if it actually broke the question, however I see no way that the compiler would pull an `std::string` out of thin air. Maybe you're not compiling the file you think? Mike van Dyke demonstrated that your original code does not trigger this error.

Comment: You wrote *"I've never used std::string in this context"* - but this does not match the question content or proposed answers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your error is that `if`s are fundamentally runtime constructs, while templates are compile time constructs.

What this really means is that, after compilation, your template function would look something like:

```
void MyClass::AddType(std::string value)
{    
    if(some_value_for_typeid(std::string) == some_value_for_typeid(bool))
    {        
        b_val = value;
    }
    else if(some_value_for_typeid(std::string) == some_value_for_typeid(int))
    {        
        i_val = value;
    }
}
```

Let's make it even more clear:

```
void MyClass::AddType(std::string value)
{    
    if(2 == 3)
    {        
        b_val = value;
    }
    else if(2 == 5)
    {        
        i_val = value;
    }
}
```

The standard if *needs* to be able to run it's body, in case the condition will ever be true. So, that gets compiled, and it fails.

---

What can be done about this? There are multiple options.

The closest to your solution is to use the new C++17 [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). This construct acts exactly like a regular `if`, only that is evaluated at compile time. The downside is that the expression must be possible to evaluate at compile time (it has to be a `constexpr` expression), and the `operator==` for `std::type_info` (the thing returned by `typeid`) is not constexpr. But, there is `std::is_same`, which does the type comparison in a constexpr fashion:

```
template<typename T>
void MyClass::AddType(T value)
{    
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {        
        b_val = value;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {        
        i_val = value;
    }
}
```

When compiling this, the whole if construct will reduce to either `b_val = value;`, `i_val = value;` or nothing.

Another option would be to simply have a function overload, by simply defining `MyClass::AddType(bool);` and `MyClass::AddType(int)`.

And a third method would be to do some [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) (which I personally think won't be a very good idea in this specific case).

Comment: Thanks @Paul92 for the detailed answer, now I see it. Unfortunately I can't use C++17, only C++ so I guess I will overload the function.

Comment: The fact that `std::type_info::operator==` isn’t `constexpr` strikes me as a phenomenal oversight. I *thought* it was sensible since `typeid` itself can’t be evaluated at compile-time for polymorphic objects, but it’s in fact entirely valid in compile-time contexts. Given this, there doesn’t seem to be a good reason for why `if constexpr (typeid(T) == typeid(int))` shouldn’t work. I had never considered this but I’m now disappointed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I totally agree, I had the same level of surprise when I got the error. It might be personal, but I do think using `std::is_same` expresses better the intent. However, this doesn't mean that I'm not still puzzled why `std::type_info::operator==` is not `constexpr`.